# Editing Sharepoint Site Homepage in Sharepoint Developer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, page-layout, sharepoint-branding

I have just edited my publishing site home page in **SharePoint Designer**. The page originally contains some web parts.

I am a newbie as far as SharePoint branding is concerned. I did the editing in **Advance Mode** when I realized that I couldn't edit areas outside my Web Part Zones and since I need to do that, I tried it using the advance mode. I edited the page adding some inline CSS styling and even added some additional Web Part Zones. Everything looked good when I previewed so I saved and thought all was okay. But to my surprise, Only my account (System Account) can see the changes I made. Every other user on the domain are still see the original page without any of my recent changes.

I have done the Check-In and Publish circle over and over again but no luck.

Does any one have any idea as to what I might have done wrong here and what I can do to fix the issue.

Comment: Did you "check-in" and then "Publish". If its a publishing site, you would need to "Approve" as well as an additional step. If you referred any external CSS/JS files, you would need to checkin those as well...

Comment: Yes I have done both "Check-in" and Publish severally. However, the page library wasn't set to "Require content approval for submitted items?" It is currently set to "No". I also need to add that the CSS were inline CSS.

Comment: If there are any changes to page layout or master page. Make sure you publish those as well. In Designer especially, you get transparently redirected from actual content page to layout page.

Comment: You are right. Editing in Advanced Mode allowed me make changes to the layout page. Apparently, I have only been publishing the site page only while leaving out the page layout. It's done now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps for publishing:

1. Select “Publish a major version,”. When
   prompted to approve the master page, click Yes. This automatically
   invokes a SharePoint master page approval page, where you
   will find your new master page listed at the top of the page.
2. Click the drop-down menu beside the master page. Select
   Approve and select the Approved radio button. Click OK. Your
   master page is now saved and approved in SharePoint.
3. Navigate to your top-level site collection, and click Site Actions -> Site Settings
4. Under Look and Feel, select the Master Pages link. For both the
   Site and System Master Page settings, select your new master
   page from the drop-down menu.

Once you click OK, your changes should be available to all users

Comment: Where will I see the the “Publish a major version” feature. The only place I have seen "Publish" is on the browser. What I have been doing is this...."Check-out page", "Edit page in SPD", "Check-In Page", then "Publish Page in browser".

Comment: Okay I have gotten it to work, taking a cue from your suggestions. Checking and approving the MasterPage for the site page fixed it.